# When it is good to reduce the user steps?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, android

I have a screen contains information about the order details as follows:

- order date and time
- delivery date and time
- delivery person and mobile number
- address to deliver to
- the order items

There are two options to view the delivery address details, the first is to use collapsible element to view the details in the same screen and the second is to redirect the user to a new screen.
What is best regarding to the usability ?

Comment: When I want to know "what is best concerning the industry," I do a competitor audit, looking at how other sites do it. That generally provides a good starting point since, presumably, that is what users are used to.

Comment: Collaborate the delivery person, mobile number and address to one. Then save it so when next time that user is ordering some item then you could simply ask him that saved address or new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking users to a new page is a pretty bad idea because it means they have to navigate back to their previous state.

A better control is accordion, modal or other, where the user can keep context with the original data